# Not given option for native monitor resolution

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, resolution

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise edition 64bit. I have the HP LP3065 monitor and (I think) I have the Intel HD Graphics 4600 adapter (at least that's what the driver is). I'm stuck at 1280x800 and can't go any higher. This is bad because the pictures and text appear blurry.

The strange thing is I connected the Philips 190B monitor (which is smaller) and it has the option to change to 1280x1024 resolution.

Comment: Install driver: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3602338&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4063 . It will tell Windows this resolution is supported.

Comment: @user996142 didn't work

Comment: What cable do you use? You must have Dual DVI-D, I believe

Comment: PS: according to manual it supports only  ``2560 x 1600``. So, you may have ``1280 x 800`` (2560 / 2 x 1600 / 2), but not 1024. Your monitor simple __does not support __ it. Here is manual http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01116432.pdf

Comment: @user996142 "Your monitor simple __does not support __ it." incorrect/unclear. The goal is to get the text and images clearer. As you state the monitor does support `2560 x 1600` but it appears the video card is the limiting factor as it can't support it that high.

Answer (score -1):

what is the driver date and version
try to get the latest driver from intel.com

the capabilities of Intel HD 4600 are

Max Resolution (HDMI)  3840x2160@60Hz 
Max Resolution (DP)  3840x2160@60Hz 
Max Resolution (VGA)  2880x1800@60Hz